# Site Wordpress alojado em Openshift retorna 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: wordpress, cdn, openshift

Tenho um site em Wordpress alojado em Openshift que tem um CDN a apontar para o origin server (Openshift). O que acontece é, ao entrar no site por vezes retorna o erro 502 Bad Gateway.

Já foram verficadas as configurações do CDN que aparentemente estõ corretas pelo que não me parece que seja a causa. No entanto, não estamos a conseguir encontrar o que está a despoletar este erro.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Se você está vendo uma mensagem de erro "502 Bad Gateway" ao acessar um site Wordpress alojado em OpenShift, isso pode ser causado por vários fatores. Algumas possíveis razões incluem:

1. Problemas de conexão com o banco de dados: verifique se o banco de
   dados está funcionando corretamente e se a conexão com ele está
   configurada corretamente no arquivo wp-config.php do Wordpress.
2. Problemas de configuração do PHP: verifique se o PHP está
   configurado corretamente no OpenShift e se o arquivo .htaccess do
   Wordpress está configurado corretamente para usar o PHP correto.
3. Problemas com o servidor web: verifique se o servidor web (como o
   Apache ou o Nginx) está funcionando corretamente e se a configuração
   do Wordpress está correta para o servidor web em questão.
4. Problemas com o OpenShift: verifique se o OpenShift está funcionando
   corretamente e se não há nenhum problema com os pods ou os recursos
   do seu projeto.

Para resolver o problema, você pode tentar fazer o seguinte:

1. Verifique o arquivo de log do PHP e do servidor web para ver se há
   alguma mensagem de erro que possa ajudar a identificar o problema.
2. Faça um backup do seu site Wordpress e tente restaurá-lo para ver se
   isso resolve o problema.
3. Se você estiver usando o Apache como servidor web, tente desabilitar
   o módulo mod_rewrite e ver se isso resolve o problema.
4. Entre em contato com o suporte do OpenShift para ver se eles podem
   ajudar a identificar o problema.